# download excel file via ajax call in razor

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, .net-6.0, export-to-excel

I am trying to download a excel file on success via a ajax call

i am able to download the file but the file is always corrupted

My Ajax is as follows

''''

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#downloadreport").click(function () {
            
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    url: "/HRDashboard/GetExcel",
                    success: function (response) {
                        debugger;
                        var bytes = new Uint8Array(response.FileContents);
                        var blob = new Blob([bytes], { type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" });
                        var link = document.createElement('a');
                        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                        link.download = "myFileName.xlsx";
                        link.click();
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                    }

                });
            


        });
    });
```

''''

and my controller is as follows

''''
public IActionResult GetExcel()
{

```
        var excel = (from i in _context.EmployeeBasicInformations where i.FormCurrentStatus == "CanditateCreated" && i.IsActive == 1 select i).ToList();

        string excelName = "NewCanditates" + "_" + (DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMddHH")) + ".xlsx";


        DataTable dt = GetTable();
        foreach (var rowdata in excel)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(
            rowdata.EmployeeId,
            rowdata.EmployeeFirstName,
            rowdata.EmployeeLastName,
            rowdata.EmployeeAadharCardNumber);
        }
        FileContentResult robj;
        using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())

        {

            var sheet = wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);
            var row1 = sheet.Row(1);
            row1.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.RoyalBlue;

            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {

                wb.SaveAs(stream);

                return File(stream.ToArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", excelName);
                //robj = bytesdata;

            }

        }

        //return Json(robj);
    }
```

''''

if i give the same controller action method as a form control i am able to download the record properly.
But when i am trying to download the data via ajax success the file is always corrupted.

Comment: Please refer to this [tutorial](https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/10730/download-excel-from-ajax-call-in-asp-net-core).